# Woocommerce - translate 'show' and 'sort by'

Tags: woocommerce

I am not able to translate "Show" and "Sort by" using loco translate plugin and my native language translation file - everything else is translated as it is supposed to!

[image: Translate "Show" and "Sort by"]

In which woocommerce file(s) are these strings created?

Comment: Are you sure those are not being added by your theme? That doesn't look like default WooCommerce to me.

Comment: That is 100% correct! Thank you again Helga :)